# Buttons not displaying from FOR loop

Tags: android, android-layout, android-button

I have been attempting to programmatically add buttons based on a list of values.

**PROBLEM:** Only one button is produced, rather than a series. This button contains the information of the last value in the array.

I gather an array of values aptly named 'values', I then use a for loop to add the buttons.

Here is the code of my loop to add buttons:

```
    public void updateButtons(List<String> values, View rootView) {

    //Find relative layout
    RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.RelativeLayoutManage);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    params.setMargins(50, 10, 50, 10);

    for (String mTrip : values) {

        //New button
        Button Postbtn = new Button(mContext);

        //Style
        Postbtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.buttonshape);
        Postbtn.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.DarkGreen));
        Postbtn.setTextSize(25);

        //set text
        Postbtn.setText(mTrip.toString());

        //set id
        Postbtn.setId(i);
        int id_ = Postbtn.getId();

        //Add to view
        rl.addView(Postbtn, params);
        Postbtn = ((Button) rootView.findViewById(id_));

        //Add listener
        Postbtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Log.v("TripNumber", Integer.toString(i));
                //TODO: Change Fragment
            }
        });
        i++;
    }
    }
```

And my corresponding layout file if needed:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/RelativeLayoutManage"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Reusing `params` like that causes problems. You should reinitialize them each time in the `loop`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by positioning each button as it is added to the layout. Simply using:

```
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, Postbtn.getId() - 1);
Postbtn.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems that they might be overlapping each other. You need to use a `LinearLayout`

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/RelativeLayoutManage"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    />
```

Comment: Should I use this instead of the RelativeLayout or have the LinearLayout within the RelativeLayout (or vice-versa)?

Comment: Use the `LinearLayout` instead

Comment: That is still not working, getting the same results.

Answer (score 0):

You are adding `Button` to `RelativeLayout`. In your current code all your buttons are present but one above other. You should make one below/above other to make all buttons visible. Else use a `LinearLayout`